# Updating npm is deleting npm?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

Running `npm update -g npm` is deleting npm from usr/local/bin.

It gives this error and when I try to run it again using sudo it is gone.

```
as-MacBook-Air:~ a$ npm update -g npm
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/a/npm-debug.log
as-MacBook-Air:~ a$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
```

try the command again with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm update -g npm
```

reinstall npm :

First uninstall node and remove node_modules. then install it again by homebrew

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.node >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh


export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
npm install -g http-server node-inspector forever nodemon
```

Comment: I reinstalled it and updated it with sudo, still so strange that it self deletes if you run it w/ out sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Sudo permissions or better try remove it and install a updated one.